# Pear::Auth access from command line

Tags: php, http, pear

I have a question about Pear::Auth PHP library. Can I somehow "login in command line". I mean can i access a resource that is protected via Pear::Auth from HttpRequest I create myself in some other script program? And can you give me an example (python, php, java or anything readable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it working (hopefully this might help somebody else - this is Python solution that can be converted to any language and allows you to login to Pear::Auth via created HttpRequest your control in your program.

```
import urllib
import httplib2
from urllib import urlencode
http = httplib2.Http()

url = 'LOGIN_URL'
# this applies to current version of Pear (had to add the authsecret)
body = {'username': 'USRENAME', 'password': 'PASSWORD', 'authsecret': ''} 
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(body))
# CAREFUL!!! HERE IS THE TRICKY PART !
# response['set-cookie'] looks like this -> 'SomeSession=longID; path=/, SomeSession=longID; path=/, authchallenge=blabla; path=/'
# you need to parse it and use only authchallanage and SomeSessionpart(just one of them I think the last one) - have no idea why, but it works. So next line needs some parsing and fixing
headers = {'Cookie': response['set-cookie']} #parseme -- this is not correnct and will not work, but you have to fix it to match your implementation
print headers

# e.g. headers = {'Cookie': 'MySession=bdfdstiq90oilkpk7n4s2q2g50; authchallenge=fddtggffg5784d359c12dfad4059', 'X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'xmlhttprequest'}#the second header is optional, I needed to access some ajax call
data = dict(argument="to_pass", eg="customerID")
resp, content = http.request("secure_URL", "POST", urlencode(data), headers=headers)
print resp
print content
```

Answer (score 0):

Really depends... on what and from where you are trying to do this... Some things that come to mind:

- Pass the credentials as command line arguments.
- Pass the credentials as part of the GET request parameters (maybe assuming SSL).
- use cURL with a cookie jar.
- implement a service layer so that these calls handle authentication in an alternate way that facilitates your needs (API with authentication that works with your existing Pear Auth).

Comment: thanks... I kinda realized it some time later... working on a solution. I semi-have it... Thanks anyway. Will post it here once done

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested in Java solution here it is:

```
public String getServerJson(){
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://"+hostToReach+"/secure/index.php");
    httpost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");

    List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", htmlUsername));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", htmlPassword));

    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, Consts.UTF_8));
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpPost ajaxPost = new HttpPost("https://"+hostToReach+"/?event_id="+pmp.getPmpEventId().getEventId().toString()+"&categories_only=true&pos=true");
    ajaxPost.setHeader("X_REQUESTED_WITH", "xmlhttprequest");
    try {
        HttpResponse catResponse = httpclient.execute(ajaxPost);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(catResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        String json = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
              json += line;
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(catResponse.getEntity());
        return json;


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Note: Cookies are handled automatically (httpclient holds them for the whole time of its existence, so you dont need to worry about that)